# Oracle : Is my DISTINCT function working properly?

Tags: oracle, select, count, distinct

I have `alphanumeric` values as my primary key. I am querying my database in two different ways and finding different results. It is almost certain that I might be missing some key point in my queries. But I get a doubt if `DISTINCT` function is working properly for `1 TB` full data of `alphanumeric` values?

First query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DOC_ID)) FROM TABLE_1;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DOC_ID)) FROM TABLE_2;
```

Difference of count is `3910`

Second query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) DOC_ID FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT(DOC_ID) FROM TABLE_1
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT(DOC_ID) FROM TABLE_2);
```

count is `0`

Does DISTINCT work properly on `alphanumeric DOC_ID`, especially if my data is huge?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. But yes, the `distinct` _operator_ works correctly on for alphanumeric values. Your two queries are not counting the same things

Answer (score 2):

Your two queries are counting the same thing.

Consider this data:

```
create table table1 (doc_id varchar(20));
create table table2 (doc_id varchar(20));

insert into table1 values ('foo');
insert into table1 values ('foo');
insert into table1 values ('bar');
insert into table1 values ('bar');

insert into table2 values ('foo');
insert into table2 values ('foo');
insert into table2 values ('bar');
insert into table2 values ('bar');
```

`count(distinct doc_id)` returns 2 for both tables.

But the following returns no rows at all:

```
select distinct doc_id
from table1
minus
select distinct doc_id
from table2;
```

So the count of that is of course zero.

If you change the sample data your second query still counts something different:

```
delete from table2;
insert into table2 values ('foo2');
insert into table2 values ('foo2');
insert into table2 values ('bar2');
insert into table2 values ('bar2');
```

`count(distinct doc_id)` still returns 2 for both tables, so the difference is still 0 between those two counts

But,

```
select distinct doc_id
from table1
minus
select distinct doc_id
from table2;
```

Now only returns `foo` and `bar` because `foo2` and `bar2` are not in `table1`.

If you add another distinct value to table2:

```
insert into table2 values ('bar3');
```

The difference in the distinct count from both tables is 1 (2 distinct values in table1, 3 in table2), but the `minus` still returns the two distinct values from the first table.